# Ionic install error status code 400

Tags: ionic-framework

Welcome I want install ionic but I can't. i installed corodva.
My error status code 400(Bad Request) why?

```
> C:\Windows\System32>npm install -g cordova
npm WARN engine xmlbuilder@2.2.1: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"4.2.2","npm":"2.14.3"})
C:\Users\kacper\AppData\Roaming\npm\cordova -> C:\Users\kacper\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\bin\cordova
cordova@5.3.1 C:\Users\kacper\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova
├── underscore@1.7.0
├── q@1.0.1
├── nopt@3.0.1 (abbrev@1.0.7)
└── cordova-lib@5.3.1 (valid-identifier@0.0.1, unorm@1.3.3, osenv@0.1.0, properties-parser@0.2.3, bplist-parser@0.0.6, semver@4.3.6, shelljs@0.3.0, cordova-app-hello-world@3.9.0, npm@2.14.3, dep-graph@1.1.0, rc@0.5.2, xcode@0.8.0, elementtree@0.1.6, npmconf@2.1.2, glob@4.0.6, plist@1.1.0, cordova-serve@0.1.3, request@2.47.0, aliasify@1.7.2, init-package-json@1.9.1, tar@1.0.2, cordova-registry-mapper@1.1.11, cordova-js@4.1.1)

C:\Windows\System32>npm install -g ionic
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10240
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\kacper\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v4.2.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.3
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET

npm ERR! network tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=400
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Windows\System32\npm-debug.log
```

Help me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install Node JS version 0.12.6, and after that

```
npm install -g cordova ionic
```

it will install Ionic and Cordova.

Answer (score 0):

firstly download and install node.js from

https://nodejs.org/en/

then restart your PC

if you are in a proxy network set your http/https proxy in CMD ( command prompt ) by

```
set http_proxy=http://[proxy_ip]:[proxy_port]
set https_proxy=https://[proxy_ip]:[proxy_port]
```

then use

```
npm cache clean
```

to clear npm's cache folder

then use the following ling to install ionic and cordovo

```
npm install -g cordova ionic
```